# Test EntityManager with Junit5 Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, junit5, entitymanager

I am trying to introduce to Spring JPA and I have difficulties running up my tests.
My gradle.build.kts looks like the following

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.10"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.4.10"
}

group = "com.pluralsight"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.0"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")

}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I am using Junit5 for my test framework. And what first I need to test is that my Flight Entity is created correctly. I am not using @SpringRunner since we are on Junit5 so I do the following:

```
package com.pluralsight.springdataoverview
import com.pluralsight.springdataoverview.entity.Flight
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import javax.persistence.EntityManager


@SpringBootTest
@DataJpaTest
class SpringDataOverviewApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private val entityManager: EntityManager? = null
    @Test
    fun verifyFlighTCanBeSaved() {
        var flight = Flight()
        flight.origin = "London"
        flight.destination = "New York"
        flight.scheduledAt = LocalDateTime.parse("2011-12-13T12:12:00")
        entityManager!!.persist(flight)
        val flights = entityManager
            .createQuery("SELECT f FROM Flight f", Flight::class.java)
            .resultList
        Assertions.assertEquals(flights.first(), flight)
    }
}
```

And I have the following in red

[image]

What dependency I am missing ?

Comment: can you add your main Spring Boot class?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple declarations of configuration (that's what your error message is saying).

It's because you are using `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataJpaTest` in the same configuration class i.e `SpringDataOverviewApplicationTests`.

Use either of it and it should be fine.

Comment: Now the erorr says "Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class"

Comment: If it helps to resolve your issue, mentioned in the question then accept the answer. It might help others.

Comment: Now it shall work. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Not it does not. Give me your github name and I will give you access to my github link